# React useForm Hook always returns input in string format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have this re-usable component and i am using react-hook-form . The problem i am facing is this always retuns entered input in string form . Suppose if user types any number this coverts the number in string format but i want this should return input based on prop type

//Reusable Input

```
  import React from "react";
        const Input = (props) => {
          const {register,rules,name,type} = props;
           return (
              <input
              type={type}
                {...props}
                {...(register && register(name, rules))}
              />
          );
        };
        
        export default Input;
```

//usage

```
             <Input
              name="discountValue"
              register={register}
              mandatory={true}
              rules={{
                required: t("Discount value is a required field"),
                min: {
                  value: 1,
                  message: t("Discount value must be greater than 0"),
                },
              }}
              error={errors?.discountValue?.message}
             type="number"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

As docs state about `HTMLInputElement`:

> string: Returns / Sets the current value of the control. If the user enters a value different from the value expected, this may return an empty string.

`input` value will be **always** type of *string*. You should convert it to a `number` manually, e.g.:

```
onChange={(event) => setValue(
   Number(event.target.value) // convert into a number
)}
```